# Questions about audit

Tags: rhel, audit, linux-audit

After executing the following instruction

```
auditctl -a always, exit -F path=/usr/bin/chcon -F perm=x -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -F key=privileged-priv_change
```

it returned the following error

> ```
> -F missing operation for auid
> ```

How to handle this?
My OS is Red Hat 7.

Answer (score 1):

Executing the mentioned cmd line leads to greater than sign `>` being interpreted as redirect operator by your shell, which is presumably `bash`. For that reason the operation for `auid` is missing, because everything after `>` is not part of the command. You probably see a file named `=1000` in your current directory.

To properly execute you have to escape `>` for example like this:

```
auditctl -a always, exit -F path=/usr/bin/chcon -F perm=x -F auid\>=1000 -F auid!=unset -F key=privileged-priv_change
```

or like this:

```
auditctl -a always, exit -F path=/usr/bin/chcon -F perm=x -F "auid>=1000" -F auid!=unset -F key=privileged-priv_change
```

Answer (score 0):

Be mindful of whitespaces

```
auditctl -a always,exit -F path=/usr/bin/chcon -F perm=x -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k privileged-priv_change
```

Comment: Sorry for the format of my inquiry
Fixed now
Then thank you for the method
But I still use the same situation